# Symfony 2 when clearing cache suddenly get Fatal err

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine, composer-php

When I run 'php app/console cache:clear' I get the following

```
Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry'  
not found in autoload.php line 13
```

I've done 'php composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader'

my symfony version is 2.3

Comment: Have you tried removing all directories from `cache` manually?